# Parse Cloud Code Push to Android Not Working

Tags: javascript, android, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

My cloud code looks like this.  It sends just fine to iOS, but when sent to an Android device, instead of a message, it gets a whole lot of JS code for the payload.:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("userPraying", function(request, response) {
    var prayersObjectID = request.params.prayersObjectID;
    var whoPrayed = request.params.theirName;
      var recipientUserId = request.params.recipientId;
    var newRecipientUserId = recipientUserId.replace('User_', '');


  var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
  pushQuery.equalTo("usersObjectId", newRecipientUserId);

    Parse.Push.send({
    where: pushQuery,
    data: {
      alert: {
      title: "Prayers Lifted!",
     body: whoPrayed + " just prayed for you.",
     "loc-args": prayersObjectID,
      },



      category : "TAGGED_CATEGORY",
 sound: "default.caf"
    }
  }).then(function() {
      response.success("Push was sent successfully.")
  }, function(error) {
      response.error("Push failed to send with error: " + error.message);
  });

});
```

When it is sent to an Android user, they get all of the Javascript code, instead of just the body of the message.  How can this be fixed?

Comment: What does the code look like for the receiver on Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data literal:

```
data: {
  alert: {
  title: "Prayers Lifted!",
  body: whoPrayed + " just prayed for you.",
  "loc-args": prayersObjectID,
  },



  category : "TAGGED_CATEGORY",
  sound: "default.caf"
}
```

Looks invalid from what I can tell in the documentation. https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#push-notifications-customizing-your-notifications

What happens if you do:

```
data: {
  alert: "Some alert",
  title: "Prayers Lifted!",
  body: whoPrayed + " just prayed for you.",
  loc-args: prayersObjectID,
  category : "TAGGED_CATEGORY",
  sound: "default.caf"
}
```

Comment: I do not know if doing "loc-args" is allowed. Alternatively the objectId could simply be sent as the alert: `data: { alert : prayersObjectID .. }`

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have a reference, but I know that you can receive a push in your app (without it generating a notification) and read the data object sent (in your case extract the loc-args entry). Then afterwards manually generate a notification to show the user. I use that method to send whole parseObjects instead of only the id, however I implemented it before they gave the whole push API an overhaul, so think it is a bit outdated the way I accomplished it. Nonetheless, it works and should still be possible with the new API.